# Using the chain rule to find the derivative of composite functions

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

If $h(x) = f((g(x))^2)$, find $h'(x)$ using the following values:

$$f(2) = 4$$
$$f(4) = -5$$
$$f'(2) = -2$$
$$f'(4) = 7$$
$$g(2) = 2$$
$$g(4) = 4$$
$$g'(2) = 3$$
$$g'(4) = 8$$

This is what I have : $f((g(x))^2) \cdot (g'(x))^2$. When I try to plug in the values, I get $f(16)$, which is not given. Thank you in advance!

Comment: After watching  f(x)  and g(x)  what you think about them, what kind of function they can be?

Comment: It’s not possible to find $h'(x)$ given those values. Presumably you’re meant to find its value for some specific value of $x$, which you haven’t mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a composition of three function, so you need to apply the chain rule twice.

$$h'(x) = f'(g(x)^2) \cdot (g(x)^2)' = f'(g(x)^2) \cdot 2g(x) \cdot g'(x)$$